# jQuery dynamic elements - how to remove element and save event data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As piece of code is better than thousand word

```
// this is our dynamic created element.,
var $test = $('<button>If you add this event is working, if you remove this, and add again, event is not working...</button>');

// this is our event
$test.click(function(){
    alert('Fooobar'); // fires only first time
});
// $test.on('click',function(){ <-- same behaviour

$('#add').click(function(){
    $('#container').append( $test );
});
$('#remove').click(function(){
    $('#container').html(''); // This is destroying all $test events!!!
});
```

How can i remove element, append it again and save events?

**JS Fiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/gPWxd/4/

I would like to remove element without destroying events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [jQuery's detach method](http://api.jquery.com/detach/).

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach()
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This
>   method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the
>   DOM at a later time.

You could detach `$test` before the `$('#container').html('');` code so `$test` could be reinserted with all events still attached.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $test = $('<button>If you add this event is working, if you remove this, and add again, event is not working...</button>');
              
// here you've to use delegate event
// using jQuery on() method

$('#container').on('click', $test, function(){
    alert('Fooobar');
});

$('#add').click(function(){
    $('#container').append( $test );
});
$('#remove').click(function(){
    $('#container').html('');
});
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gPWxd/5/)***

For delegate event *(aka live event)* handling you need to use `on()` like:

```
$(Parent).on(eventName, target, handler);
```

Here `Parent` is a static-element that is a container to `target` and `target` is the element to which the `event` will bind.

Read more about jQuery ***[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)*** method.

---

### You can also do following

```
var $test = $('<button>If you add this event is working, if you remove this, and add again, event is not working...</button>');

$('#add').click(function() {
    $('#container').append($test.on('click', function() {
        alert('Fooobar');
    }));
});
$('#remove').click(function() {
    $('#container').html('');
});
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gPWxd/10/)***

Comment: That's it! But what if I need to put `$test` somewhere else than `#conatiner`?

Comment: @EXQStudio as you `$test` contains only `<button>` so it firing the click event to all buttons. you can use any `class` name to distinguish the dynamically added button.

Answer (score -2):

Bind the event's function to a parent element.

```
$('body').on('click', 'button', function(){
    alert('Delegated Click function');
});
```

Replace `button` with your selector.

Comment: I know this trick, but this doesn't work for me. Thanks anyway. I would like to remove element without destroying events.

Comment: @EXQ Studio -- There's no way to remove an element from the DOM (cleanly) and save it's events. This is why we delegate functionality. Choosing to go against the grain will cause unnecessary overhead, and also brings challenges (such as this) to the plate. I don't think you're going to find repreive.